# Swift UIButton Image color

Tags: swift, image, uibutton

I want put the image on button, so I

```
var cancelImage = 
    UIImage(named: "close.png")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)

self.viewCancel.setImage(cancelImage, for: .normal)
```

`close.png` color is skyblue but build the project, it seems like `UIButton` default color(I can't explain that but I guess, it maybe `.systemBlue`)

I want show the image's color.

How I can show it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use

```
withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

you're telling the system you want to use the image as a template. This allows it to use the UIButton's `tintColor` property to tint the image. If you want to use the image's normal colors, you should remove the

```
.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

and just use

```
UIImage(named: "close.png")
```

Here's the doc for [alwaysTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/renderingmode/alwaystemplate)

Comment: sure, should remove 'withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)' as a normal state

Comment: @Chris Hansen So I remove the .alwaysTemplate, but it's color like blue, but set .alwaysOriginal, it is what i want. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

> I want show the image's color

Then why did you say `withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)`? You are slapping yourself in the face and then complaining that your face is being slapped.

Instead, say `withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)`.